# DL query in Protege related to equivalent class and object property

Tags: owl, ontology, protege4, dlquery

[image: Kindly click here to view the Ontology Snapshot for understanding the question]

I have shown a snapshot of an Ontology in the figure above.

I try to **Execute** a **DL query** from Protégé 5.0.
The query is:

```
hasVolume value Apple.
```

Apple is an instance of Fruit (see Figure Link). The *object property* is *hasVolume*. The result shows *no output* in the instance section (GUI). I am expecting the **following result** of the above query:

```
LowVolume.
```

The *object property axiom* of Apple shows "**Apple hasVolume LowVolume**".

**What modifications** in the query (or Ontology) to be made so that I get the **desired result**.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: Your query would return "all instances that are connected to the instance Apple via property hasVolume". You need to invert the relation.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand your question right, you need to get the value of `hasVolume` property, for `Apple`. I guess you writing a reversed (wrong) query. Try writing the following in your DL tab:

```
 inverse (hasVolume) value Apple
```